# failed to find library teserract41.dll for platoform 64x- After installing vc_redist.x64.exe

Tags: c#, dll, tesseract

I have a program that uses the tesseract library and I want to use it on other computers so I send to other computer the debug folder. Suddenly I got this runtime error message on the other computer:
`failed to find library teserract41.dll for platoform 64x`

Before I intalled the vc_redist.x64.exe I had the error: `failed to find library leptonica-1.80.0.dll for platoform 64x`
Now I get the error in the title and I don't know what else can I do.
In the 64x folder there is this dll.

In my local computer, when I run my program from the debug folder everything works fine.

I installed all the three exe files from this link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0

```
x86: vc_redist.x86.exe
x64: vc_redist.x64.exe
ARM64: vc_redist.arm64.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding dll to the project folder

Comment: Which folder did you put it in? \bin\x64?